# Eevee transparency and transmission

Tags: transparency, eevee-render-engine

I have this kind of weird scene I'm working on where I have a cube of water (principled shader with transmission set to one and IOR of 1.333). Inside of that cube is a plane where I'm using a gradient mask make the plane either fully transparent or just slightly.

With cycles this works like a charm
[image]

but in Eevee it doesn't. The plane dissappears.
[image]

Any sugestions how to accomplish this? I'm guession screen space reflections/refractions and alpha settings on the materials matters but I can't figure out how to set them

Blend file is attached but missing hdri.
[download file](https://gofile.io/?c=HUM4hY)

Regards,

Björn

Comment: Read the refraction section in [cycles vs eevee 15 limitations of real time rendering](https://cgcookie.com/articles/blender-cycles-vs-eevee-15-limitations-of-real-time-rendering)

Comment: At least try playing with the different transparency types (setting them to hashed)

Answer (score 1):

The solution in my case was so simple I somehow missed it. I changed my mask from black/white to grey/white and accomplished what I was after.